# JavaFx context menu styling with css - background color on full width

Tags: css, javafx, contextmenu

I want to style my context menu but I can't get rid off white area between menu-item and context-menu border, see example.
[rendered context menu with css styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2sXf.png)

I want that color fils whole area up to context menu border like this 
[ecpected styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76edI.png)

My css styles

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-effect: null;
    -fx-border-color: #D6D9DF;
    -fx-border-width: 0.5;
    -fx-border-radius: 4;
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
}

.menu-item {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-pref-height: 28px;
}

.context-menu .separator {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.menu-item .label {
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-padding: 6 16 8 12;
    -fx-text-fill: #2D3845;
}

.menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #EAECEF;
}

.menu-item:pressed  {
    -fx-background-color: #D6D9DF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding

```
yourcontextmenuname.getStyleClass().remove("context-menu");
```

and then change your CSS to refer *yourcontextmenuname* by ID. If that does not work do the same with menu-item.